# How to debug injected javascript code in IE compatibility mode?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, internet-explorer

I need to inject some Javascript scripts to IE and then invoke some methods.

I tried the following simple C# code (the Javascript code is to build xpath from a known HTML element).

```
string xpath = @"
(function(win) {
    ""use strict"";
    var doc = win.document;

    if (doc._xpath_installed) return;
    doc._xpath_installed = true;

    doc.createXPath = function (node, optimized) {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            return '/';
        }

        var steps = [];
        var contextNode = node;
        while (contextNode) {
            var step = _xPathValue(contextNode, optimized);
            if (!step) {
                break;
            }  // Error - bail out early.
            steps.push(step);
            if (step.optimized) {
                break;
            }
            contextNode = contextNode.parentNode;
        }

        steps.reverse();

        var stepvalues = [];
        steps.forEach(function (step) {
            stepvalues.push(_steptostring(step));
        });
        return (steps.length && steps[0].optimized ? '' : '/') + stepvalues.join('/');
    };

    var _xPathValue = function (node, optimized) {
        var ownValue;
        var ownIndex = _xPathIndex(node);
        if (ownIndex === -1) {
            return null;
        }  // Error.

        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                if (optimized && node.getAttribute('id')) {
                    return _stepnew('//*[@id=""' + node.getAttribute('id') + '""]', true);
                }
                ownValue = node.localName;
                break;
            case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
                ownValue = '@' + node.nodeName;
                break;
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
                ownValue = 'text()';
                break;
            case Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:
                ownValue = 'processing-instruction()';
                break;
            case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
                ownValue = 'comment()';
                break;
            case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
                ownValue = '';
                break;
            default:
                ownValue = '';
                break;
        }

        if (ownIndex > 0) {
            ownValue += '[' + ownIndex + ']';
        }

        return _stepnew(ownValue, node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_NODE);
    };

    var _xPathIndex = function (node) {
        // Returns -1 in case of error, 0 if no siblings matching the same expression,
        // <XPath index among the same expression-matching sibling nodes> otherwise.
        function areNodesSimilar(left, right) {
            if (left === right) {
                return true;
            }

            if (left.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && right.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                return left.localName === right.localName;
            }

            if (left.nodeType === right.nodeType) {
                return true;
            }

            // XPath treats CDATA as text nodes.
            var leftType = left.nodeType === Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE ? Node.TEXT_NODE : left.nodeType;
            var rightType = right.nodeType === Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE ? Node.TEXT_NODE : right.nodeType;
            return leftType === rightType;
        }

        var siblings = node.parentNode ? node.parentNode.children : null;
        if (!siblings) {
            return 0;
        }  // Root node - no siblings.
        var hasSameNamedElements;
        for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; ++i) {
            if (areNodesSimilar(node, siblings[i]) && siblings[i] !== node) {
                hasSameNamedElements = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!hasSameNamedElements) {
            return 0;
        }
        var ownIndex = 1;  // XPath indices start with 1.
        for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; ++i) {
            if (areNodesSimilar(node, siblings[i])) {
                if (siblings[i] === node) {
                    return ownIndex;
                }
                ++ownIndex;
            }
        }
        return -1; 
    };


    var _stepnew = function(value, optimized) {
        return {
            value: value,
            optimized: optimized || false
        }
    };

    var _steptostring = function(step) {
        return step[""value""];
    };
})(window);
";
```

And then I try to inject the xpath string and invoke a method,

```
// doc is the html document (type: mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)
// element is the html element (type: mshtml.IHTMLElement)

doc.parentWindow.execScript(xpath, "JScript");
    
object[] args = new object[2];
args[0] = element;
args[1] = 1;
object result = doc.GetType().InvokeMember("createXPath", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, doc, args);
```

It works fine in Internet Explorer 11 (Windows 10).

However, when I add the website to Compatibility View (settings-> compatibility view settings), the InvokeMember call throws exception "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101", which means there are some script errors in the Javascript code.

My question is, is there a way to debug into this Javascript code in the above situation? Without debugging it is almost impossible to find the root cause only based on the information 0x80020101.

Comment: Why not just do this directly in C#?

Comment: 1. There are already lots of library codes available (some open source) in Javascript, change everything will take a lot of efforts and will also be slow in run time.  2. currently these javascript codes work in IE9 and above, in Edge and Firefox and Chrome (for chrome/firefox/edge, Javascript is the only viable solution, C# can't directly get their doc/element like IE), I would still like to use Javascript for IE compatibility mode if possible.

Comment: There are also a lot of C# libraries as well to do this. In fact, the XPath support there is arguable better than what is written here. You could use `XmlDocument` to load the HTML and then use its XPath methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have script errors in your JS code, why don't you trace the client-side code's execution with `console.log()` or `console.debug()` so that you know what is happening in your application ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to debug code in Edge IE mode, you can use IEChooser to open Internet Explorer DevTools, as follows:

1. In Windows, open the Run dialog box. For example, press the `Windows logo key` + `R`.
2. Enter `%systemroot%\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe`, and then click OK.
3. In IEChooser, select the entry for the IE mode tab.

For more details, you could also refer to this doc: [Open DevTools on a tab in IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/ie-mode/#open-devtools-on-a-tab-in-ie-mode).